# 'Serilog' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'

Tags: serilog, rollingfilesink

I am trying to install serilog and I'm getting error

> PM> Install-Package Serilog
>   Install-Package : 'Serilog' already has a
>   dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Serilog
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],   InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

`Microsoft.CSharp` is already referenced in my project

Comment: Update the NuGet extension in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks that worked

Comment: Seems to be required for packages that have added compatibility with .NET Core. Not sure why.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I have VS 2012 Update 5, I updated the package manager to 2.8.60318.667 and it still didn't work.  What worked for me is it force nuget to install a previous version 1.5.14:   Install-Package Serilog -Version 1.5.14

Comment: Also, to force the update of Nuget.exe you can run "nuget update -self" from the command line within the .nuget directory of your solution. Updating nuget via "Tools -> Extensions..." did not update the exe for an existing project. If you do this you shouldn't have to do the workaround in my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

As @[Tieson T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534109/tieson-t) said, Update "Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio" from Visual Studio Window > Tools > Extensions and Updates > Click Updates tab. Select Nuget plugin and update. Then restart the visual studio after installation complete. I tried (Windows 8.1 64bit & Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate) and it works.

Comment: Note to self: remember to go into TeamCity and do the same: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NuGet

Answer (score 1):

To add to this. I had a similar issue but the problem was due to our build server being based on TFS 2012 and using an old version of MSBuild (which we can't update in the near term). Everything built and ran fine locally, but when the build server tried to run we got the same error.

The workaround I found was to go into the packages folder of the solution, find the package having the issue (in my case Serilog.2.3.0 and the associated Sink packages I had installed). Open the "lib" folder and you should see some folders associated to the various .Net frameworks. Delete the netstandard folders which correspond to the .Net Core versions.

The downside to this is you have to check in the folders you modify like this so MSBuild doesn't try to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the 2 steps below, it works for me or teamcity/jenkins

1. If you still using the Nuget CommandLine 2.8, please try to upgrade to 3.5.
2. If you using the private Nuget Server, Please update the Serilog.2.3.0.nupkg with the steps below:

   2.1 Update Nuget Spec File:
       Remove 
       
       ...
     
     
       
       ...

   2.2 Remove the folder lib/netstandard1.0 and lib/netstandard1.0

   2.3 Then redeploy the Serilog.2.3.0.nupkg to your private Nuget Server

Comment: Remove the group for targetFramework=".NETStandard1.0" and  targetFramework=".NETStandard1.3" for update the Serilog.nuspec